# Restrictions on custom SCIM URL

Tags: url, scim

The examples provided in rfc7644 and rfc7643, the URL's of different resources are in the format,

```
http://<domain>/v2/<Resource_Name>
```

One of my requirements is to use URL's like, `/v2/x/a/resource1`  , `/v2/x/b/resource2` and to be the resources of the same type.

Does SCIM protocol offer this kind of flexibility?

But found the usage of this URL `GET /api/scim/v2/groups/:group_path/Users` [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/scim.html)

Answer (score 0):

If by resource1 and resource2 you mean users and groups endpoint, then no. You supposed to provide base URL to IDP to be used for every endpoint (User, Groups).

So your base URL has to look like:
https://yourscimdomain:/scim/v2///
and IDP will add to the end of it Users or Groups endpoint.